# How to get the index of a key in a ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

If I have

```
footnotes = { "apple" => "is a fruit", "cat" => "is an animal", "car" => "a transport"}
```

How can I get the index of these?, something like:

```
footnotes["cat"].index
# => 1
```

Comment: There's no such thing as index in Hash.

Comment: But you can do: `footnotes.keys.index('cat')`

Comment: Do you know that, in most programming languages (including Ruby), index starts with 0?

Comment: @BroiSatse: That isn't guaranteed to work (but it'll work as all current Ruby implementations preserve the insertion order).

Comment: @cremno - it is guaranteed to work for ruby 1.9+.

Comment: If you need an index you're probably using the wrong data type.

Comment: Spud, I respectfully disagree. I've found many valuable uses of "insersion-order preservation" for hash key-value pairs, and if we make use of that property, what's wrong with the concept of a key-value pair having an index?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I am aware this could be easily managed with other data structures, however as many correct answers this can be addressed when the dictionary preserves the order. I particularly like @BroiSatse 's answer (You could add yours as an answer, as it seems to be the shortest).

Answer (score 11):

There's no need to first retrieve the keys:

```
footnotes.find_index { |k,_| k== 'cat' } #=> 1
```

As to the question of whether hash key-value pairs have an index (since v1.9), I would just point out that the Ruby monks decided to supply us with [Enumerable#find_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index), which of course means `Hash.instance_methods.include?(:find_index) #=> true`.

Comment: Great answer @cary-swoveland, this can be used to find index with different matches (using keys or values).

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
footnotes.to_a.index {|key,| key == 'cat'}
# => 1
```